# Element ID is visible when I inspect the page, but returns null when I try to use getElementById and click event to trigger a function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, getelementbyid

I'm building a Chrome extension that will allow me to interact with the underlying web app/page via content.js.

I have a working model for one web app I work with regularly and am trying to build another extension to work a separate web app I use.

I've been stumped by the below code when run with the second web app returning `null`:

```
   document.getElementById('completedButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
      cfPulse.taskCompleted();
    });
```

When I inspect the page I can see this button in the html, can see the ID clearly, and just can't seem to get it to be recognized by the code.

Here's the HTML I can see:

```
<button data-v-69a50b9d="" tabindex="0" type="button" class="q-btn inline relative-position q-btn-item non-selectable justify-left q-btn-rectangle q-btn-flat q-focusable q-hoverable text-blue" id="completedButton">
    <div class="q-focus-helper">
    </div>
        <div class="q-btn-inner row col items-center q-popup--skip justify-center">
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="q-icon material-icons">done</i>
                        Complete
        </div>
</button>
```

I tried doing all sorts of things with `window.onload` `document.readyState`, etc. and nothing seems to allow me to get this bit of js to run after the page is fully loaded.

I have zero control over the underlying app as it is a 3rd party tool.

Expected outcome is that the underlying function will be called when the `completedButton` is clicked.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe there is another element with the same id?

Comment: try logging the whole `document` in console and verify if the document that is being referred contains the elements of your first web app.

Comment: @Michelangelo Thanks, but I confirmed this is a unique element ID.

Comment: @MM I did that as part of my troubleshooting and confirmed that it is included in the `document`.  I'm thinking of adding a timer just to confirm that it is/isn't a timing thing.

Comment: Update - I added a timer - 10 seconds - and my getElementById worked perfectly.